# how Base64 API understands end of String while decoding

Tags: base64

Sometimes I am unable to provide the entire String .but with truncated String also Base64 API can decode it .How does base64 understands end of string

Answer (score 1):

> How does base64 understands end of string

You haven't said *which* base64 API you're using, but typically they require that the string you provide is a multiple of 4 character in length. Each 4 characters in a base64 string corresponds to 3 bytes.

If the overall binary data is not a multiple of 3 bytes, the final 4 characters contain *padding* of the `=` character to indicate the desired length. See the Padding section in the [Wikipedia Base64 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more details.

Comment: I am using commons-codec-1.4.jar.I want to pass an Input String and decodes  using Base64 API.But I am unable to to do it for few String which has a truncated version present.So I need to know how can I end the String forcefully and generate a partial Image so i need to know a generic pattern which will end the Truncated String and generate a partial image.

Comment: @user2295281: Well you could either just truncate at a 4 character boundary, or add appropriate `=` characters to make it up to a 4 character boundary. Be aware that if this is really image data, you may well not end up with a valid image that way though.

Comment: hi i think the problem is not with the Base64 but after getting the byte array when I am passing the byte array inside BufferedImage using BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in); it is showing the error 
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: @user2295281: Well exactly - if you've not got a full image file, it's not likely to be a valid image file, is it? Hence the end of my previous comment. I wouldn't *expect* `ImageIO` to deal with damaged data. I'm sure there are tools out there which do, but I don't know whether there are Java APIs around them. At this point it's not really about base64 though - it's about how to deal with a truncated image file. If you want to pursue this, I suggest you ask a new question about that, leaving out the base64 part.

Answer (score 0):

In Base64 each character represents one of 64 values: a 6-bit value. But bytes are 8-bit values, so base-64 encoded data must somehow be a multiple of *both* 6 and 8.

Well, one 6-bit character is obviously not going to fill one byte, but two 6-bit characters (12 bit) fill not exactly two bytes. Three 6-bit characters (18 bit) fills a little bit more than two bytes, but not three. However, four 6-bit characters (24 bit) fills exactly three 8-bit bytes.

So a base64 string must be a multiple of 4 characters in length, as to be able to fill a whole multiple of 8-bit bytes with data. This means you can split base64 encoded data at any multiple of four characters and it will work. But if you split the data at any other position, it will probably not work.

This also holds for the end of the data. For example, if I have only six 8-bit bytes to encode (40 bit) but the base64 string must then be two times 4 6-bit characters in length (48 bit) then I am 8 bits of data short. For those remaining (partial) 6-bit characters the `=` character to indicate that there follows no particular data.